# validate format string for numeric values in excel (dna)

Tags: excel, excel-interop, excel-dna, vba

I'm using a excel dna to manage an excel addin. There, I'm applying a numeric format to a cell using `Range.NumberFormat = myformat;`. I don't know in advance the string myFormat, it is defined in a backend.

In the good cases myFormat is something like "0.00;(0.00)" or "# ##0,00\ _€;[Red]-# ##0,00\ _€", in others something like "toto". In the latest case, the display in the excel cell is ########## or something that doesn't make sense.

So, is there a way to check that the string myFormat is a valide numeric format for excel before applying the format to the cell?.

Thanks,
Mario.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `#######` just means the cell isn't wide enough to display the value.  Your example formats returned values for me.

Comment: Yes, with the correct format examples, excel displayed the value formatted correctly and it fit in half a cell. But with the incorrect format example, excel displayed #### sometimes and the value of the format (for instance, "toto") other times.

Comment: What are examples of incorrect formats? If you format is "toto", then yes you'll get 0=toto, 1=toto, -1= -toto.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. Sorry. What I want is very simple, I have a string "myFormat" that I want to apply as a numberformat to a cell using excel dna. But first I want to check if the string "myFormat" is a valid number format. For instance "0.00;(0.00)" is valid and "toto" is not. I don't know in advance the string "myFormat", they are define in some backend.

Comment: In that case maybe you can make an array of acceptable formats and check your string against each element in that array.  myarray = array("0.00;(0.00)", "# ##0,00\ _€;[Red]-# ##0,00\ _€", "_(#.##_);(#.##)", "# ???/???").  If your string doesn't conform to any of your acceptable formats then change it to one that is.

Comment: That will work if I know all the possible combinations for a format. Even there, maybe it would be better to  create a regex but I don't know how excel manipulates the formats strings.

Comment: I was thinking maybe something like `IsNumericFormat = IsNumeric(Target.Text)` would return a boolean based on the displayed value in a cell.  You'd have to put the value in a cell and apply formatting first though, and numbers like 5.00% would return false as the % isn't numeric.  I was also thinking `IsNumericFormat = IsNumeric(Format$(Target.Value, Target.NumberFormat))`, but again for numbers like -20 the cell displays `- 20` while Format$ displays `- 020 _€`, but it works for certain number formats.  Just throwing it out there as a possible solution that's full of holes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tester()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("F1")' Formatted with 2 decimal places
Set rng2 = Range("G1")' Formatted with 6 decimal places

If rng1.NumberFormat <> rng2.NumberFormat Then
Beep
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this is good to check if we have two different formats in two ranges, but I want to verify if a given string is a valid number format to apply to a cell

Comment: I'm just giving you the logic you need.  I wasn't trying to write the code for you Mario.  if variable.numberformat = myformat then do something, else; do something else.

Comment: yeah, but my question is very different. I want to check if myformat is valid before applying the format. If I do rng1.NumberFormat="toto", excel will display something that doesn't make sense. So, I want to check if myFormat is valid or not before actually going to the line rng1.NumberFormat = myFormat

Comment: I understand that.  As you already know, there is no error when you put a bad numberformat into a cell or column.  It will just give you gibberish data.  As far as I can see, the only way to make certain that any string contains a valid numberformat is to check it against a list of known good formats.  If it doesn't match any of them then it is not a good numberfromat.  Is there a limit to how many bad format strings you receive from your backend software?  Perhaps it would be easier to compile a list of those bad format strings and check your variable against those.